# Are callbacks in Javascript really methods calls? If so how are they 'cascaded'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, callback

For example, take this code from Angular.js:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
           templateUrl: 'page/hello.html',
           controller: 'mainCount'
       })
       .when('/pag', {
           templateUrl: 'page/hello.html',
           controller: 'secondCount'
       })
});
```

So `$routeProvider` is an object, and it seems like `.when` (the callback) is a function invocation. If so, how do these two method calls above get invoked 'one on top of the other'?

Normally, I'd expect this to happen:

`object.method().method()`

the second method invokes on the object returned  by the first method. Clearly, this is not happening in the Angular example above. So what's going on here?

Comment: Hmm, i suppose the `when()` method returns `$routeProvider`, allowing you to continue calling functions on it?

Comment: `.when` is a method call and has nothing to do with callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are callbacks in Javascript really methods calls?

Maybe. Being a method is orthogonal to being a callback.

A method call is when a function attached to an object is called.

A callback is a function that is passed as an argument to another function call.

It is possible that a function which accepts a callback will attach it to an object and call it in that context, but not required.

> So $routeProvider is an object, and it seems like .when (the callback)

`when` isn't a callback in this instance. Promises have a method called `when` which accepts a callback as an argument, but you aren't dealing with a promise here and you aren't passing a function to `when`.

> .when (<strike>the callback</strike>) is a function invocation.

Yes. The return value of `when` is an object. That object is the same object that the first `when` was invoked on, and it still has a property called `when` whose value is a function.

This is **method chaining** not callbacks.

> So what's going on here?

Just sensible return values. Take a look at this simple example:

```js
function Incrementor() {
  this.value = 0;
}

Incrementor.prototype.up = function() {
  this.value++;
  return this;
}

var i = new Incrementor();

document.body.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode(
    i.up().up().up().value
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot makes sense now. Javascript is a fickle language.

Comment: Accepted as answer. Both answers were correct but I felt this more closely answered the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The `.when` method of `$routeProvider` is returning its `this` in order to allow chaining. Each call to `.when` adds to the list of stored routes.

```
$routeProvider = function $routeProvider() {
  this.routeList = [];
};

$routeProvider.prototype.when = function when(string,object) {
  this.routeList.push(string, object);
  return this;
};
```

Similarly for a `$q` promise, the `.then` method gives the `$q` service a function to be called at a later time which the `$q` service stores on its list or its "queue" but in that case it returns a new promise. Each successive call to the `.then` method returns a new promise.

This is an extremely important point. Promises do not return mutated versions of themselves. They return new promises with their `.then` method. Lack of this understanding has been the folly of many library developers.

Comment: Interesting. So in the case of $q promise, if you call .then 10 times with different functions as params, will it give you 10 new promises (rather than the same promise with 10 functions in it)?

Comment: @Warrshrike Yes. But beware of `.success`. It is buggy. It returns the **old** promise. That's why it's been deprecated. For information on the deprecation of `.success` look at the latest [AngularJS $http API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)